# Why are few rows not getting deleted with below script?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database, sql-delete

I am running below script where I am deleting those records having IDs not present in one of two tables.

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#tempTable') IS NOT NULL DROP TABLE #tempTable

CREATE TABLE #tempTable (ID int)

INSERT INTO #tempTable
SELECT ID FROM mainTable
WHERE ID NOT IN  ((select distinct(ID) from TABLE1) union
        (select distinct(ID) from TABLE2))
        

SET @delRows = 1;

WHILE (@delRows > 0) 
BEGIN

BEGIN TRANSACTION

DELETE TOP (10000) mainTable 
WHERE ID IN (
SELECT ID from #tempTable
    )
SET @delRows = @@ROWCOUNT; 
PRINT CAST(@delRows AS VARCHAR) + ' rows deleted'

COMMIT TRANSACTION 
CHECKPOINT 
END

DROP TABLE #tempTable
```

It gets executed successfully but if I run delete query by replacing delete with select clause then I am getting some 700+ rows.
But Ideally we should get 0 rows because we are deleting all the records for which IDs are not present either in table1 or table2.

When I check those IDs in table1 or table2, I get 0 record. This is strange.

What am I missing here ? Does union or distinct clause causing issue ? Or Is batch delete statement not proper ?

Comment: Temp table maybe still there for some reason.

Comment: At least this should return 0 rows, right ? Its returning some 700+ rows. select * from mainTable WHERE ID IN (SELECT ID from #tempTable) and all 700 + IDs are not present in both Table1 and Table2

Comment: "we are deleting all the records for which IDs are not present either in table1 or table2."  So in the 700+ rows in the SELECT, are they indeed IDs that are not present in either table1 or table2?

Comment: Is there any trigger on mainTable? An instead of trigger can substitute you delete with any other delete that does non touch some rows, so your delete deletes nothing but the rows are still there in MainTable